# can we have two elements with the same name under the same complex type

Tags: xml, xsd

Please tell if this xsd declaration is syntactically correct or not. This is a 'native xsd' portion. Functionally it is working fine, i want to know if there is any syntax violation etc in it according to general schema rules.
Note that i have two elements with the same name 'data'.

```
   <xsd:complexType name="rowType">
        <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element name="data" type="xsd:string" maxOccurs="3" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="," />
          <xsd:element name="data" type="xsd:string" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="${eol}" />
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:complexType>
```

Answer (score 1):

It violates the Unique Particle Attribution constraint, because when you get the second "data" element in the instance, it is not known whether to match it against the first "data" particle or the second.

Comment: Thanks Michael, still got a query though, I am using nxsd instead of xsd here. I guess the ambiguity in matching the elements will be handled by 'nxsd:style' and 'nxsd:terminatedBy' here. Will it be okay to assume it?

Comment: I haven't the faintest idea what nxsd is.